# NuxtJS and Custom JS file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm encountering a problem when adding custom scripts on NuxtJS. I purchased a template with all assets, but the JS is loading inconsistently.

I've noticed that some jQuery elements are called before view rendering.
The specific plugin is "menuzord" and I tried loading it prior to the  tag from within the app.html file, but without success. Then I tried from the plugin folder, but nothing.

Where is the exact place for adding a custom script for NuxtJS?

Thx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom script in `nuxt.config.js` file, and add in `head` section like below:

```
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js', async: true, defer: true }
    ],
  },
```